# "Duplicate key 'PostStatus'" in Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have multiple questions pertaining to cloud functions.

**Questions 1**

I'm trying to update my field that if one condition is met a field, say `PostStatus` should be updated to `"Started"`. When a different condition is met the same field should be updated to to `"Completed"`. However, when I write the statement and try to deploy it to the Cloud Function Console I'm being given error that `Duplicate key 'PostStatus'`.

How do I write this code properly?

code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();
const min = "* * * * *";

exports.scheduled = functions.pubsub.schedule(min).onRun(async (context) => {
  const batch = database.batch();
  const {docs} = await database.collection("ADSGHANA").get();
  docs.map((doc) => {
    const {
      TimestampArrival,      //This is Timestamp saved in the database
      TimestampDeparture,    //This is Timestamp saved in the database
      TimeToDelete,         //This is Timestamp saved in the database
      PostStatus,           //This is a string saved in the database
    } = doc.data();
    const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
    const starting = now > TimestampDeparture;
    const ending = now > TimestampArrival;
    const delete = now > TimeToDelete;

    batch.set(
        database.doc(`ADSGHANA/${doc.id}`), {
          Timestamp: delete? TimestampDeparture : now,
          PostStatus: starting? "Started" : PostStatus,
          PostStatus: ending? "Completed" : PostStatus, //this is where the duplicate occurs
        }, {
          merge: true,
        },
    );
  });

  await batch.commit();
});
```

**Question 2**

Using the same code above, after this condition is met `now > TimestampDeparture;`, a code like that of Flutter should be implemented. Like this

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collectionName")
                          .doc(uid)
                          .collection("subCollectionName")
                          .where("AdStatus", whereNotIn: ["Passenger cancelled",
                           "Rejected"])
                          .get()
                          .then((value) =>
                              value.docs.forEach((element) {
                                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection(collectionName)
                                  .doc(uid)
                                  .collection(subCollectionName)
                                  .doc(element.id)
                                  .update({"AdStatus": "Started"});
                                    }));
```

This code is for a button widget and I want to implement something similar with the cloud function.

That is, that doc ID should update a field `AdStatus` in all its corresponding subCollection, provided the `.where()` conditions are met.

How do I do this? I not used to JS coding so I'm stuck.

It would be much appreciated if I get help. Thank you all.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question for next one to be answered. Or should I delete it and create a new post?

Comment: As said: please limit yourself to one question per post. Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
let val = PostStatus;
if (starting) val = "Started";
if (ending) val = "Completed";

database.doc(`ADSGHANA/${doc.id}`), {
  Timestamp: delete? TimestampDeparture : now,
  PostStatus: val
}...
```